# Faking A Keyboard or Mouse Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, .net-4.5

I've been trying to figure out how to fake, not simulate, keyboard and mouse input. By this I mean the system goes through the process as if the actual event occurred, such as a mouse click, but does not actually perform the event, such as clicking the mouse.

Or if you wanted to make the system think your mouse had moved even though it did not. Sort of a "virtual" move that doesn't actually happen/effect the mouse.

Is it possible to override the simulated mouse clicks and events to make them not actually click while the system thinks they have?

Comment: This looks like it could possibly help: https://movemouse.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry @LarsTech it's a regular windows forms application. I'm going to check that out Thomas, thanks for the quick replies!!

Comment: You either add input events to the [input queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/13/10499047.aspx), or you don't. If you do, the system will think the click happened as if the user did it with the actual mouse. If you don't, the system will not do anything, and you'll have to call your event handlers [manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683018/c-sharp-faking-a-keyboard-or-mouse-event#comment51307983_31683018).

Comment: You can just call the method directly.  Example: `OnMouseClick(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: Windows is inherently an event based system. If Windows ":thinks " you clicked a button, then its going to notify all processes that are subscribed to that event and those processes do whatever they want. What you basically are trying to do is create an event, but suppress the notification of that event.

Comment: I am not able to follow the movemouse @ThomasStringer. I'm not extremely familiar with alot of the code. It looks like it would be useful as far as the stealth mode but I cannot follow the code to see how it is implemented. Do you understand it?

Comment: Is suppression possible @Icemanind?

Comment: I'm very curious, what could you achieve with this?

Comment: For me it was mainly the mouse aspect. I wanted to be able to have the system fake a mouse move, "jiggle", with 0 interruption to the actual mouse. So virtually moving the mouse in the background separate from actual mouse movements. @loli

Comment: @Schwagmister Its possible in your own application, but not system wide.

Comment: Do you have any references on how to do it locally in my application but not system wide? @Icemanind

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for. Events are just to handle what happens when you do something, it's not what causes something to happen.

Comment: @Schwagmister - Just subscribe to the event, but leave the event handler blank. Voila!

Comment: @Icemanind even though I got my issue working with lrb's suggestion I still am curious about your idea. Do you have an example of the call I would make to subscribe to an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice project that wraps the keyboard and mouse. Here is the [mouse input simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WindowsInput/MouseSimulator.cs) file for reference. To see the lower level work, navigate to the `WindowsInput.Native` namespace in that project.

Comment: I havent found time to update this but I did come across that and it does exactly what I needed. I got my implementation working correctly. Thanks for the response !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all of your help. I was finally able to achieve what I wanted via lrb's answer.

I used that library to fake input and in the grand scheme of things I was trying to make a mouse jiggler but not actually effecting the user's mouse in case the application was running while the user was using the mouse. Which is why I wanted to "fake" the mouse rather than move the actual mouse. Thanks again for everything this was amazing.

Icemanind I'm still curious about your idea with subscribing an event rather than having an event handler. This would allow me to induce something like a mouse click without actually clicking correct?